# ASP.NET IdentityUser and profile photo stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I would like to create a little application in ASP.NET Core 1, using ASP.NET Identity Core. I'm doing an API, and my front is Angular JS

I have extended IdentityUser to add a column (Photo, a byte array).

I encounter a little problem, at the creation, I do this :

```
if (vm.PhotoFile != null)
{
      user.Photo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vm.PhotoFile);
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.PhotoUrl))
{
      HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
      var response = myClient.GetAsync(vm.PhotoUrl).Result;
      user.Photo = StreamHelper.ReadToEnd(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
}
```

This is code working well, but when I'm querying users using SQL Server, I can see that the column size in important...

**First, is there a way to reduce the size of the stream ?**

Secondly, when i'm querying the list of users, the response size (if I include profile photo) is important...

**Does it exist a solution to counter this problem ? (just make a list of users with photos) ?**

Thank you

Comment: Side note: `ASCII.GetBytes` seems incredibly wrong. I wouldn't expect an image to be stored in ASCII. What's wrong with `File.ReadAllBytes`

Comment: Thanks. The size is important when i'm querying data (I used small resolution images), is there a way to resize them (example 100*100) and minify the stream ?